# How to make SOAP API request and check for response in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, soap

I need to make a SOAP API request and retrieve response in Swift. I am new in SOAP API and Swift. I have an API path, API Method and Input Parameters. The output is in JSON.

API path : http://testapp.Lzoom.com/V3/UserProfile_V3.asmx
API Method: Check_MobileFlag_V3 ()

Input Parameters:

SessionId : String

Token : String

TimeStamp : String

Output Parameter:  JSON

Result : Integer

1 : Force User to Change Mobile

-100 : Internal Error

-98 : User credential are wrong, Logout User

Comment: If there's any online method to check Soap Api's, please refer them too. Like for Rest Api's I use POSTMAN, RestClient, etc.

Comment: What have you done so far that didn't work?

Comment: @Ali thanks for the response. I got it implemented successfully. Body of soap request modifies every time which I managed. thereafter following below instructions clicked. thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as i understand from your question you don't need full soap framework to make call and handle responses.In such case you should use simple xml parser and construct your own soap xml calls.

i will advise you use to use cocoapods and integrate [AEXML](https://github.com/tadija/AEXML) into your project

Here it's simple xml soap format to make call

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap:Header>
    <m:Trans xmlns:m="http://www.w3schools.com/transaction/" soap:mustUnderstand="1">234</m:Trans>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:GetStockPrice>
      <m:StockName>AAPL</m:StockName>
    </m:GetStockPrice>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and it how could you construct it with AEXML

```swift
let soapRequest = AEXMLDocument()
let attributes = ["xmlns:xsi" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xmlns:xsd" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"]
let envelope = soapRequest.addChild(name: "soap:Envelope", attributes: attributes)
let header = envelope.addChild(name: "soap:Header")
let body = envelope.addChild(name: "soap:Body")
header.addChild(name: "m:Trans", value: "234", attributes: ["xmlns:m" : "http://www.w3schools.com/transaction/", "soap:mustUnderstand" : "1"])
let getStockPrice = body.addChild(name: "m:GetStockPrice")
getStockPrice.addChild(name: "m:StockName", value: "AAPL")
println(soapRequest.xmlString)
```

after than preparing your soap calls you can use any networking library

Comment: Is there any online service to check SOAP API's like POSTMAN for REST API's?

Comment: there is Chrome extension for this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/boomerang-soap-rest-clien/eipdnjedkpcnlmmdfdkgfpljanehloah?hl=en